# Grid Control : Run time Error when run at Windows XP in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, grid, controls

OS : Windows 7 32 bit
Developping Tool : Visual Studio 2008

Problem : 
When run at Windows 7 it's ok, but at XP there is assertion error at DEBUG mode, invisible grid control error at RELEASE mode. (like you can see it as pictures below)

Situation :

- The grid control class, I used for the program, was downloaded from [code-project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/gridctrl.aspx). (I think I can't upload the file in stackoverflow? If you need it, plz tell me.)
- I used to use this class in VS 6.0. It's my first time using it in VS 9.0. There was no error when I used it in VS 6.0.
- There is no compiling error when I compile the program in Windows 7 and XP.
- On Windows 7, it runs well both at DEBUG and RELEASE mode.
- On Windows XP, running exe file in the DEBUG folder gives an assertion error. And when I run exe file in the RELEASE folder, the grid control doesn't show up.
- And I also tried to compile on XP with Visual Studio to see if there is any error, but it only gives run-time error.

Error :

> Debug Assertion Failed! Program : ...
>   File : .../gridctrl_src/gridcell.cpp
>   Line : 228
>
> For information on how your program
>   can cause an assertion failure, see
>   the Visual C+ documentation on
>   asserts.

The below is gridcell.cpp source code at the error line.

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CGridDefaultCell

CGridDefaultCell::CGridDefaultCell() 
{
#ifdef _WIN32_WCE
    m_nFormat = DT_LEFT|DT_VCENTER|DT_SINGLELINE|DT_NOPREFIX;
#else
    m_nFormat = DT_LEFT|DT_VCENTER|DT_SINGLELINE|DT_NOPREFIX | DT_END_ELLIPSIS;
#endif
    m_crFgClr = CLR_DEFAULT;
    m_crBkClr = CLR_DEFAULT;
    m_Size    = CSize(30,10);
    m_dwStyle = 0;

#ifdef _WIN32_WCE
    LOGFONT lf;
    GetObject(GetStockObject(SYSTEM_FONT), sizeof(LOGFONT), &lf);
    SetFont(&lf);
#else // not CE
    NONCLIENTMETRICS ncm;
    ncm.cbSize = sizeof(NONCLIENTMETRICS);
    VERIFY(SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS, sizeof(NONCLIENTMETRICS), &ncm, 0));
    SetFont(&(ncm.lfMessageFont));
#endif
}
```

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue with *CGridCtrl* while porting a project from VC6 to VS2012.

In your project set `_WIN32_WINNT` to the lowest target platform you want your application to support. That's `0x0501` for XP SP1.
No code changes should be required in *CGridDefaultCell*.

[Related discussion](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/1ca0e823-9a8c-408a-b82a-23f7214fef5d) on MSDN

Answer (score 0):

Answer my own question...

SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS, ...) problem

```
// Initially use the system message font for the GridCtrl font
        NONCLIENTMETRICS ncm;
        memset(&ncm,0,sizeof(NONCLIENTMETRICS));
        ncm.cbSize = sizeof(NONCLIENTMETRICS);
#if (WINVER >= 0x0600)
        ncm.cbSize -= 4; //<== ADD HERE!! 
#endif
        BOOL f = SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETNONCLIENTMETRICS,sizeof(NONCLIENTMETRICS), &ncm, 0);

        VERIFY(f);
        if(f){
            memcpy (&m_LogFont, &ncm.lfMessageFont, sizeof (LOGFONT));
            m_LogFont.lfHeight = -MulDiv (11, dc.GetDeviceCaps (LOGPIXELSY), 72);
            m_LogFont.lfWeight = FW_NORMAL;
            m_LogFont.lfOutPrecision = OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS;
            m_LogFont.lfClipPrecision = CLIP_DEFAULT_PRECIS;
            m_LogFont.lfQuality = DEFAULT_QUALITY;
            m_LogFont.lfPitchAndFamily = DEFAULT_PITCH | FF_DONTCARE;
            m_LogFont.lfCharSet = ANSI_CHARSET;
            _tcscpy (m_LogFont.lfFaceName, _T ("Courier New"));
        }
```